# How do I find a method's nesting in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, reflection, nested, constants

In Ruby, constant lookup is affected by nesting and methods retain their nesting.

For example, if I have these modules:

```
module A
  X = 1
end

module B
  X = 2
end

module Foo
end
```

I can define a method `Foo.a` that has a nesting of `[A, Foo]`:

```
module Foo
  module ::A
    Module.nesting #=> [A, Foo]
    def Foo.a
      X
    end
  end
end

Foo.a #=> 1
```

And a method `Foo.b` that has a nesting of `[Foo, B]`:

```
module B
  module ::Foo
    Module.nesting #=> [Foo, B]
    def Foo.b
      X
    end
  end
end

Foo.b #=> 2
```

The difference becomes apparent if I define `Foo::X`:

```
Foo::X = 3

Foo.a #=> 1  <- still resolves to A::X
Foo.b #=> 3  <- now resolves to Foo::X
```

But how do I determine the nesting of a given method?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure why `Foo.a` and `Foo.b` are defined and available in main.

Comment: @EricDuminil I'd say because of `::Foo`, it refers to the top-level constant.

Comment: Didn't realize that top level modules can be nested into others, wow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
Foo.method(:a).to_proc.binding.eval('Module.nesting')
#=> [A, Foo]

Foo.method(:b).to_proc.binding.eval('Module.nesting')
#=> [Foo, B]
```

Tested with Ruby 2.2.1 and 2.3.1.
It doesn't work with Ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: You said _"I cannot test it on my phone"_ – was this a lucky guess or did you knew that it would work?

Comment: Let's say it was an educated guess, helped with the official Ruby documentation.

Comment: I experimented a bit with `Method#owner` when you posted the question, but didn't come far, because `Foo.method(:a).owner==Foo.method(:b).owner`. I thought about it on the way to work, and noticed that `Method#to_proc` could give more information about the methods.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no `Method#nesting`. Relying on `eval` always feels wrong ;-)

Comment: Yes it does. I don't know if it's possible to replace a Proc with another one, or append a Block to a Proc.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about it the wrong way. There is no such thing as *"nesting of methods"*. Constants are nested somewhere. Nesting has path resolution connected to names of modules and classes. Methods are contained within a module/class (be it *"normal"* or singleton).

---

Where a method is placed is semantical. There is a concept, similar to `self`, which determines where a method will be defined, called default definee. There is no keyword for it, but it's roughly equivalent to:

```
kind_of?(Module) ? name : self.class.name
```

---

Where a constant is placed/searched for is purely syntactical. When you refer to `X`, it does not care the least bit if you placed it a method or not:

```
DEEP_MIND = Object.new

module Foo
  X = 42
end

module Foo
  module Bar
    def DEEP_MIND.talk
      p X
    end
  end
end

DEEP_MIND.talk # => 42

module Foo::Bar
  def DEEP_MIND.talk
    p X
  end
end

DEEP_MIND.talk # => uninitialized constant
```

All it cares about is what the *"current nesting"* on the line of the code where you tried to reference it.

---

Now, if you actually wanted to find *"the current nesting inside the body of the method"*, then you need some way to pretend you are actually there.

Sadly, I don't think there is any other way other than the one showed in [@Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910464/2423164). Using block with `instance_eval`/`instance_exec` will give you the nesting of where the block was defined.

Comment: _»There is no such thing as "nesting of methods"«_ – but in order to evaluate a method, Ruby has to know its nesting. In my example, `Foo.b` first resolves to `B::X` and later to `Foo::X`. It doesn't simply resolve statically to `::B::X`, it respects the nesting at the point of its creation, i.e. `[Foo, B]`.

Comment: @Stefan *"but in order to evaluate a method, Ruby has to know its nesting"* - not really. It just needs to know which object it's invoked on. The constant is not resolved by the method. It's resolved by the current context in the code. It just so happens that methods have a convenient way to get the current context/closure - `#binding`. Wherever you are, method or not, what the current nesting is can be accessed via `Module.nesting`. It uses the current binding. `binding.eval('Module.nesting')` just uses a different binding to pretend it has a different context.

Comment: @Stefan, ok, you can say a method knows it's binding, and the binding (wherever you are, method or not) knows the current nesting. In that sense a method knows the current nesting of where it was defined. But that is only incidental, it's not the idea that methods are nested similarly to constants.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I mean / want. Trying to use the `module` keyword within a method definition results in a syntax error ("module definition in method body"). A method therefore has a single binding / nesting from start to finish. This gave me the impression that "its nesting" is stored along with the method.